# Setting default emacs font for initial and new frame

Tags: fonts, emacs, debian

This or a similar question has been asked so many times that there exist tens of answers, but seemingly little consensus, so I will risk the wrath of the monitors and ask my own version:

I am using emacs 26.1 on Debian bullseye.  I have acquired a 4k monitor, on which the default emacs fonts appear way too large.  Reading many of the related answers on this site, I have found that adding the line

```
(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :height 60)
```

to my `.emacs` file results in a font size of 6 pts in the initial Emacs frame, which is great.  The problem arises when I try to open a new frame with `C-x 5 2`.  The new frame opens with a font size of 11.  That can be changed through `Options` ->set default font and reducing from 11 to 6.  However it would be much easier if the new frame opened with the correct font size (6).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my cocoa emacs on Mac OS X to load my .emacs visual customizations for new windows (any document opened after the first)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909593/how-do-i-get-my-cocoa-emacs-on-mac-os-x-to-load-my-emacs-visual-customizations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `set-face-attribute` for face `default`, but use `nil` or `t`, not `(selected-frame)` as the value of argument `FRAME`:

   ```
   (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 60)
   ```

   `C-h f set-face-attribute` tells you:

> > **`set-face-attribute`** is a compiled Lisp function in `faces.el`.
> >
> > `(set-face-attribute FACE FRAME &rest ARGS)`
> >
> > Set attributes of `FACE` on `FRAME` from `ARGS`.
> >
> > This function overrides the face attributes specified by `FACE`’s
> >     face spec.  It is mostly intended for internal use only.
> >
> > **If `FRAME` is `nil`, set the attributes for all existing frames, as
> >     well as the default for new frames.  If `FRAME` is `t`, change the
> >     default for new frames only.**
> >
> > ...

2. Or you can customize option `default-frame-alist`, to provide the frame parameter values you want. That affects all new frames (ordinary ones, at least). `M-x customize-option default-frame-alist`.

   You can set frame parameter `font` - e.g.:

   ```
   "-*-Lucida Console-normal-r-*-*-12-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1"
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much.  The first part of your solution, replacing (selected-frame) by nil works like a charm.  Emacs wouldn't let me enter 'M-x customize-option default-frame-alist' as a single entry, it insists on a '-' after the word option.  I tried entering 'M-x customize-option' followed by 'default-frame-alist', but that only gives a help item.

Comment: Yes, I meant `M-x customize-option RET` followed by `default-frame-alist RET`. That should open Customize for that user option.

Comment: after 'default-frame-list RET' I see an interactive page that has live buttons for 'Search', Revert...', 'Apply', Apply and Save', 'INS' and 'State'.  How would I use those to set 'font' to the value you suggested?  It may well be that I just don't know eneough to ask a cogent question??  I have accepted your answer, Thanks once more forr the very helpful answers

Comment: Click `INS`, which means "insert". Then you'll see places to enter the name of a frame `Parameter` and its `Value`. Enter `font` for the `Parameter`. Enter a string font name (with the enclosing `"` chars) for the `Value`. Each time you define a parameter to include you get a new `INS` button to let you insert another one. And you get a `DEL` button to delete the one you inserted.

Comment: You should see this at the top of the Customize buffer: **For help using this buffer, see [Easy Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) in the Emacs manual.** Follow that link to "Ask Emacs" - even better than asking here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my init, I have the following to hook into `after-make-frame-functions` where I setup fonts (taken from somewhere online, surely),

```
(defun my-frame-init ()
  ;; eg.
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                      :font "NanumGothicCoding-14"
                      :weight 'normal))

(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
              (lambda (frame)
                (select-frame frame)
                (my-frame-init)))
  (my-frame-init))
```

Comment: I have added the code you supplied verbatim to my .emacs file and restarted.  Sadly `C-x 5 2` still starts a large frame with a large font.  Not sure what you mean by 'taken from somewhere on line, surely'  Could you supply example?

Comment: added an example line from my frame config -- by "taken from online" I just meant I'm sure I got this solution online somewher